# Almost exact formula for sum of Euler Phi function $\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)$

Tags: number-theory, summation, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

Solving a problem, I needed a formula for $\Phi(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)$, where $\varphi(k)$ is Euler's notorious totient function, that counts the number of numbers between $1$ and $k$ that are coprime with $k$. I looked it up online and found that the best we were able to get until now is
$$\Phi(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)=\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2+\mathcal{O}\left(n(\log{}n)^{\frac{2}{3}}(\log\log{}n)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)$$
which becomes, when calculating:
$$\Phi(n)\simeq\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2$$
and the error is quite small.

Howewer I needed an exact formula, and so, with some combinatorics and probability, I came up with the following:
$$\Phi(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)\simeq\left({n\choose 2}+1\right)\prod_{p\ prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{p}}\right\rfloor}^2\right)$$
The proof is simple but quite long, you can find it here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xxjmgmcwqfgb.

For simplicity I will call the product function $L(n) \triangleq\left({n\choose 2}+1\right)\prod_{p\hspace{1pt}prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{p}}\right\rfloor}^2\right)$ from now on.

It is interesting to notice that the product taken over all prime is the same as the product taken only over the primes s.t. $p<n$, and this makes the calculation a lot easier.

Unfortunately (and I have no idea why), $L(n)$ still doesn't compute the exact value of $\Phi(n)$, but the error it provides is a lot smaller than the one of $\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2$, here are some examples:

$$ \Phi(2064)=1\,295\,506\hspace{2cm}\Phi(2064)-L(2064)=58.0496 \hspace{2cm}\Phi(2064)-\frac{3}{\pi^2}2064^2=592.093 $$
the error with $L$ is $ 0.0044$ %, the error with $\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2$ is  $0.0457$ %.

$$ \Phi(10463)=33\,282\,718\hspace{2cm}\Phi(10463)-L(10463)=-8.35606 \hspace{2cm}\Phi(10463)-\frac{3}{\pi^2}10463^2=6500.06 $$
the error with $L$ is $ -2.51063 \cdot 10^{-5}$ %, the error with $\frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2$ is  $0.0195298%$ %.

There are even values where $\Phi(n)-L(n)\ll 1$, for example if $n=502$ we have:
$$ \Phi(502)=76\,698\hspace{2cm}\Phi(502)-L(502)=0.0215688 \hspace{2cm}\Phi(502)-\frac{3}{\pi^2}502^2=97.9693 $$
where the error for $L$ is $2.81217 \cdot 10^{-5} $ %

I have no idea how to interpret these results. If someone knows why the formula fails I'd be delighted to hear.

**EDIT:**

As @Peter Košinár pointed out, the correct formula should be
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \varphi(k)\simeq\ \frac{1}{2}\left(1+N^2\prod_{p\ prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{N^2}{\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{p}}\right\rfloor}^2\right)\right)$$

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about the use of the equals sign and simultaneously saying "Unfortunately (and I have no idea why), $L(n)$ still doesn't compute the exact value of $\Phi(n)$". Since you say your argument uses probability, is this a heuristic argument?

Comment: You are right, its a bit confusing. I derived this formula with a probabilistic approach followed by algebraic manipulations, so before seeing the results I thought the formula worked, since I proved it. But it doesn't, so I guess maybe the proof I gave wan't so rigorous.

Comment: So you are modelling the primes (or coprime pairs of integers or something?) using some random model? Then it's not surprising that it's pretty close, but also not surprising that proving it's correct is very difficult.

Comment: what do you mean by random model?

Comment: Probably nothing more or less than you mean by "probabilistic approach".

Comment: Ok, yea you're right then, I also suspected the mistake was in considering probability a solid way to start the proof.

Comment: "Unfortunately (and I have no idea why)" - You only need to consider the product of primes less than $n$ because of the floor term. If $p>n$, then $\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{p}}\right\rfloor$ is zero, meaning the terms in your product from that point on are all one. Hence, the value of the product does not change from that point.

Comment: @LucaArmstrong please read carefully what I wrote in the question. That was not what I "have no idea why".

Comment: @Zima It was just that you added a comma straight after, so it didn't seem like you were talking about your next point. Apologies for the misunderstanding though

Comment: @StevenClark I added the proof here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xxjmgmcwqfgb

Comment: [This discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412065) on what it means to think heuristically about the divisibility of integers by primes as random events might be helpful.

Comment: I only reviewed the first page of your proof so far, but I found a couple of errors. First you state that $S(n+1)=S(n)+\phi(n)$ whereas actually $S(n+1)=S(n)+\phi(n+1)$, but I'm not sure this really matters since your subsequent formula $S(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \phi(k)$ is correct. Second, your denominator in $P(N)=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \phi(k)}{\binom{N}{2}}$ seems incorrect to me since it doesn't account for the case $S(1)=1$ and you always include the pair $\{1,1\}$ in the count, so it seems to me the formula should really be $P(N)=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \phi(k)}{\binom{N}{2}+1}$.

Comment: Thank you. First one was just a typo, I will fix that. For the second one, I didn't notice, I will fix that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very nice problem! I see two separate problems in the proof; one easy to fix, one not so much. The "big" one explains why there *must* be difference between $L(n)$ and the correct value of the sum. On the other hand, the "easy" one actually made the expression *closer* to the expected values; thus adding to the confusion.

---

We'll start with the "easy" one: The proof works by expressing a specific probability in two different ways. Since we are looking for *exact* match rather than just some kind of asymptotic behaviour, we need to be *very* careful to make sure it is indeed the same scenario being considered in both cases.

The second part of the proof considers all $N^2$ pairs of integers from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ (the two integers in each pair are considered completely independently). On the other hand, the first part of the proof originally considered only pairs *distinct* integers from the same set, without paying attention to their order. This disregarded the pairs $(i,i)$ completely; even though the numerator of the fraction counted the pair $(1,1)$ as "winning". The attempted fix included the extra "winning" pair $(1,1)$ in the denominator, thus arriving at the expression

$$P(N)\overset{?}{=}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^N \varphi(k)}{\binom{N}{2}+1}$$

This is not sufficient, though, since it ignores the existence of the other ordered pairs of the form $(i,i)$. The correct expression for $P(N)$ looks as follows:
$$P(N)=\frac{1}{N^2}\left(2\sum_{k=1}^N \varphi(k)-1\right)$$

The sum counts the number of winning pairs $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i\leq j\leq N$; this includes the special pair $(1,1)$. Since every pair can also be reversed and yield another valid pair, the sum is doubled; the extra $(-1)$ accounts for the $(1,1)$ being identical to its reversal.

Now, if we apply this *correct* value of $P(N)$ and equate it to the quantity found by the second approach:
$$P^*(N)=\prod_{p\ prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{N^2}{\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{p}}\right\rfloor}^2\right)$$
we'd get
$$L^*(N)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+N^2\prod_{p\ prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{N^2}{\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{p}}\right\rfloor}^2\right)\right)$$

As indicated at the beginning, this function is actually *worse* estimate of $\sum_{k=1}^N\varphi(k)$ than the one provided by incorrect reasoning!

---

Now, the "big" issue is a lot more subtle and lies in the phrase "*But being divisible by a prime number or being divisible by another prime number are independent events.*". Is that *really* the case?

Consider a simpler problem: We are given two distinct primes, $p$ and $q$ and look at positive integers up to $N$. What is the probability of a (uniformly) randomly chosen number not being divisible by $p$? Clearly, it's $\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor\right)$. The same applies of $q$, of course. But what is the probability of a number being divisible by neither $p$ nor $q$? Is it the product of these two probabilities (as independence would require)?
Sometimes yes, but most of the time no.

For a specific example, consider $N=20$ and $p=7$ and $q=11$. The probability for non-divisibility by $p$ is $\frac{18}{20}$, and by $q$ is $\frac{19}{20}$. However, the probability of "neither $p$, nor $q$" is $\frac{17}{20}$ rather than $\frac{18}{20}\times\frac{19}{20}$. It's not difficult to see why: if $N$ is smaller than $p\times q$, the two divisibility conditions are actually mutually *exclusive* (which is as far from independence as it can be). Note that even $N$ being greater than $p\times q$ is not sufficient to provide independence; that only happens when $N$ is a *multiple* of $p\times q$.

Yes, asymptotically, as $N$ grows, the probability will *converge to* the product of the two probabilities, but for a fixed $N$, there is no guarantee of equality. The whole thing gets even more complicated if we consider more than two primes; and even more so if we are looking at *all* the primes up to $N$, where even increasing $N$ and looking at asymptotic behaviour is complicated by further and further terms appearing in the product.

The same kind of a problem appears when considering *pairs* of integers and their common divisors; not-sharing-divisor-$p$ and not-sharing-divisor-$q$ are not really independent.

---

It is not difficult to see that the mistake of considering the probabilities as independent when they are not over-estimates the correct values; so the values given by $L(N)$ should be overestimates of the desired sums. The values of $L(N)$ are not always so; precisely because of the "easy" mistake. Explaining *why* those incorrect estimates are better would most likely require much deeper analysis of the interplay between primes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your amazing answer to the problem. Now I understand why the formula fails, and also how you modified it, and I am gonna edit the post and write your correct formula. To be honest I am quite sad that it was not a computational error but rather  a conceptual error, because this means the formula is never going to work perfectly. I will accept your answer since you clarified all my doubts about the problem.