# A simple way to obtain $\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, probability-theory, prime-numbers, independence

Let $ p_1<p_2 <\cdots <p_k < \cdots $ the increasing list in set $\mathbb{P}$  of all prime numbers .
By sum of infinite geometric series we have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$, for $0<r<1$. For all $s>1$ and $r=\frac{1}{p_k^{s}}$ we have
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\dfrac{1}{1-p_{1}^{-s}}
&
=
&
1+\dfrac{1}{(p_1^s)^1}+\dfrac{1}{(p_1^s)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(p_1^s)^3}+
&
\!\!\cdots\!\!
&
+\dfrac{1}{(p_1^{s})^{\alpha_1}}+
&
\cdots
\\
\dfrac{1}{1-p_{2}^{-s}}
&
=
&
1+\dfrac{1}{(p_2^s)^1}+\dfrac{1}{(p_2^s)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(p_2^s)^3}+
&
\!\!\cdots\!\!
&
+\dfrac{1}{(p_2^s)^{\alpha_2}}+
&
\cdots
\\
\dfrac{1}{1-p_{3}^{-s}}
&
=
&
1+\dfrac{1}{(p_3^s)^1}+\dfrac{1}{(p_3^s)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(p_3^s)^3}+
&
\!\!\cdots\!\!
&
+\dfrac{1}{(p_3^s)^{\alpha_3}}+
&
\cdots
\\
\vdots 
&
\vdots
& 
\vdots
&
\vdots
&
\vdots
&\vdots
\\
\\
\vdots 
&
\vdots
& 
\vdots
&
\vdots
&
\vdots
&
\vdots
\\
\dfrac{1}{1-p_{k}^{-s}}
&
=
&
1+\dfrac{1}{(p_k^s)^1}+\dfrac{1}{(p_k^s)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(p_k^s)^3}+
&
\!\!\cdots\!\!
&
+\dfrac{1}{(p_k^s)^{\alpha_k}}+
&
\cdots
\\
\vdots 
&
\vdots
& 
\vdots
&
\vdots
&
\vdots
&
\vdots
\\
\end{array}
$$

And the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic tells us that every integer $ n> 1$ can be decomposed uniquely as a product 
$$
 n= p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}}p_{i_2}^{\alpha_{i_2}}\cdots p_{i_k}^{\alpha_{i_k}}
$$ 
of powers of prime numbers $p_{i_1}< p_{i_2}< \cdots < p_{i_k}$ for integers $\alpha_{i_1},\alpha_{i_2},\ldots,\alpha_{i_k}\geq 1$. Since $
 n^s= (p_{i_1}^s)^{\alpha_{i_1}}(p_{i_2}^{s})^{\alpha_{i_2}}\cdots (p_{i_k}^s)^{\alpha_{i_k}}$ and
 using brute force with I can prove that
$$
\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
But I would like to know if there is a simple and elegant way to achieve this result is up through the above list.

Comment: Heres a fantastic video/playlist that talks about the Euler product https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3qSCWNXZKg&list=PL32446FDD4DA932C9&index=2

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I absolutely love this result, I literally cannot stop from getting goosebumps and smiling whenever I think about it. It is a proof from **probability theory**! I learned it in David William's *Probability with Martingales*, of which it is part of exercise E4.2.

Fix $s>1$ and recall that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n^{-s}$, so we aim to show that $1/\zeta(s) = \prod_p(1-p^{-s})$ where of course $p$ ranges over the primes.

First, define a probability measure $P$ and an $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variable $X$ such that $P(X=n) = n^{-s}/\zeta(s)$ (for example take $P(\{n\}) = n^{-s}/\zeta(s)$ and $X(\omega)=\omega$).  Let $E_k := \{X \text{ is divisible by } k\}$. We claim that the events $(E_p : p \text{ prime})$ are *independent*. We note that
$$
P(E_k) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X=ik) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(ik)^{-s}}{\zeta(s)} = k^{-s} \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s)} = k^{-s}.
$$

Then if $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are distinct primes we have $$\bigcap_{i=1}^n E_{p_i} = E_{\prod_{i=1}^np_i},$$ so that
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n E_{p_i}\right) = P(E_{\prod_{i=1}^np_i}) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i \right)^{-s} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{-s} = \prod_{i=1}^n P(E_{p_i})
$$
so our independence claim is proved.
Then we note that $1$ is the unique positive integer which is not a multiple of any prime. Hence
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = P(X=1) = P\left(\bigcap_p E_p^c\right) = \prod_p(1-P(E_p)) = \prod_p(1-p^{-s}).
$$

Comment: This is indeed a cool proof! Picky point: how does one justify the independence of infinitely many events (used in the last line) when one has shown only independence of finitely many events?

Comment: @GregMartin Independence of an infinite collection is defined to mean every finite subcollection is independent (which I did show). Then we have $$P(\cap_p E^c_p) = P(\cap_n \cap_{p \leq n} E^c_p) = \lim_n P(\cap_{p \leq n} E^c_p) = \lim_n \prod_{p \leq n} (1-P(E_p)) = \prod_p(1-p^{-s}).$$ Of course $p$ ranges over primes and $n$ ranges over natural numbers (should be clear by context).

Comment: Note that one never has to worry about convergence of products of probabilities because $a_n := \prod_{i=1}^n P[\cdots]$ is a monotone (decreasing) sequence bounded below by $0$, this is why I left out my previous comment from my original argument.

Comment: @nullUser Congratulations to replicate here this fantastic race. It displays a fantastic correspondence between primality of numbers and independence of measurable sets.

Comment: @nullUser, see follow-up question by Elias at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435561/proof-of-the-infinitude-of-primes-by-probabilistic-methods

Comment: There's a slight jump between the notion of finite independence and infinite independence. I'm sure there is a justification, but currently it eludes me why one can do that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What part confuses you? Make sure to read my comment above.

Comment: @nullUser: You have shown $E_p$ 's are independent , but in the last line of the proof aren't you assuming $E^c_p$'s are independent ?

Comment: nullUser, I felt kind of the same when I learned that result last year \m/ @SouvikDey Independence of $E_p$'s implies independence of $E_p^C$'s

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write $\prod\limits_{j=1}^\infty$ than $\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty$, since $\text{“}i\text{''}$ is conventionally used for something else? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: same as this? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435604

Comment: @MichaelHardy i think addressed in comments in another answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435604) 'While it is true that ζ(s) is real for s∈[0,1) (not at s=1), this is not necessary information to the proof. We consider only real s>1, and take the limit from the right, so as to only use s>1 throughout. – nullUser Jan 15 '16 at 19:03' ?

Answer (score 5):

Let $s$ for which $\Re(s)>1$ then, for all $p \in \mathbb{P}$ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^{ks}}=\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$

Now let $A(N)$ be the set of all strictly positive numbers such as all prime divisors are at maximum $N$.

Then $$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P},\text{ }p<N}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}=\sum_{n \in A(N)}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

Obviously $\{1,...,N\}\subset A(N)$, then

$$\left|\zeta(s)-\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P},\text{ }p<N}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\right|\le \sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{n^{\Re{(s)}}}$$

When $N$ goes to infinity it gives the result.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that this question is quite old and maybe you are already aware of this proof, but since your profile still says that you would like to have some *elegant proofs*, here's one simple sieving technique that I absolutely adore and find worth sharing on a platform like MSE-

$$\zeta(s)=1+\frac 1{2^s}+\frac 1{3^s}+\frac 1{4^s}+\frac 1{5^s}+\dots$$
So,
$$\frac 1{2^s}\zeta(s)=\frac 1{2^s}+\frac 1{4^s}+\frac 1{6^s}+\frac 1{8^s}+\dots$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first one, we have
$$\left(1-\frac 1{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)=1+\frac 1{3^s}+\frac 1{5^s}+\frac 1{7^s}+\frac 1{9^s}+\dots$$
So,
$$\frac 1{3^s}\left(1-\frac 1{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)=\frac 1{3^s}+\frac 1{9^s}+\frac 1{15^s}+\frac 1{21^s}+\frac 1{27^s}+\dots$$
Subtracting the fourth equation from the third one, we have
$$\left(1-\frac 1{3^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)=1+\frac 1{5^s}+\frac 1{7^s}+\frac 1{7^s}+\frac 1{11^s}+\frac 1{13^s}+\frac 1{17^s}+\dots$$
It is clearly visible that this seiving technique can be continued to have
$$\dots \left(1-\frac 1{11^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{7^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{5^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{3^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)=1$$
which gives
$$\zeta(s)=\frac 1{\left(1-\frac 1{2^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{3^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{5^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{7^s}\right)\left(1-\frac 1{11^s}\right)\dots}$$
In other words,
$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p\in \mathbb P}\frac 1{1-p^{-s}}$$
which completes the proof.

To make this proof rigorous, we need only to observe that when $\mathfrak R(s)>1$, the sieved RHS approaches $1$, a fact which is a consequence of the convergence of Dirichlet series of $\zeta (s)$.

Comment: Wonderful this proof. Thank you so much for sharing it.

Comment: @EliasCosta I will forward your thanks to Euler :)